# how to fix error "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Tags: python, list, intervals

i have this code

```
#fsa and ghf are both lists of equal length

#this code divides each of the elements within each list into multiple lists in six element intervals
start = 0
end = len(fsa)
for x in range(start,end,6):
    l = fsa[x:x+6], [x]
    m = ghf[x:x+6], [x]

# this code should be able to fetch the first and last element in those lists of six for 'ghf'(but i can't seem to make it work)

for x in m:
    m1 = m[x]
    m2 = m[x+5]

    print(m1, m2)
```

Whenever i run that last code i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\Fmark 1\venv\mark 1.py", line 53, in <module>
    m1 = m[x]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: `m` is a tuple, `x` is the list in the first position of that tuple, so what do you think `m[x]` represents?

Comment: That means X is a list. Not a slice or int.

Answer (score 3):

`m` is a tuple and `x` is a list.

You can't index a tuple with a list. You have to use an int or slice.

Answer (score 0):

you want to make `l` and `m` two lists, but with this code you're just reassigning new values to that variables. so you have at first to declare them:

```
start = 0
end = len(fsa)
l = []
m = []
```

and then append values to the lists:

```
for x in range(start,end,6):
    l.append(fsa[x:x+6])
    m.append(ghf[x:x+6])
```

then, if you want to take the first and last element (I'll do as in the example, where you only want the first and last of each element of `m`, and not also of `l`), given that the length of each little list is 6:

```
for x in m:
    m1 = m[0]
    m2 = m[5]

    print(m1, m2)
```